# Using PowerShell to send DELETE API request

Tags: powershell, api

I am using PowerShell to read a database, get a list of user IDs and then delete everyone from a particular course.  Because the course contains over 1000 records I have added pagination (per_page=100) to my request statement.  However, my delete statement only removes 100 records at a time.  When I re-run it, it will remove the next 100 and so on. I want it to remove everyone at once. I think that I need to place a Do While loop on my API requests but am not sure if that is the proper way to do it.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I have included the code here.

```
    $RequestURL = "$domainurl/$CourseID/enrollments?type[]=StudentEnrollment&state[]=active&per_page=100"

    $Results = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $RequestURL -Headers $headers -Method GET -UseBasicParsing
    $json = $Results | ConvertFrom-Json # Convert the results from JSON
    
    foreach($obj in $json) { 
    $ID = $obj.id # user id  
    $URL = '$domainurl' + $CourseID + '/enrollments/' + $ID + '?task=delete'
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -Headers $headers -Method Delete -UseBasicParsing | write-host
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered _removing_ `per_page=100` again?

Comment: Yes.  When I remove the per_page=100, it only deletes 10 records.  With that statement included, it deletes 100.